# Transaction in PostgreSql

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, transactions, db2

I'd like to realize following scenario in PosgreSql from java:

- User selects data
- User starts transaction: inserts, updates, deletes data
- User commits transaction

I'd like data not be available for other users during the transaction. It would be enough if I'd get an exception when other user tries to update the table.

I've tried to use `select for update` or `select for share`, but it locks data for reading also. I've tried to use `lock` command, but I'm not able to get a lock (`ERROR: could not obtain lock on relation "fppo10"`) or another transaction gets lock when trying to commit transaction, not when updating the data.

Does it exist a way to lock data in a moment of transaction start to prevent any other call of `update`, `insert` or `delete` statement?

I have this scenario working successfully for a couple of years on DB2 database. Now I need the same application to work also for PostgreSql.

Comment: On the one hand, you say you want data to be unavailable for others during the transaction. On the other hand, you don't like that `select for update` locks data for reading, which seems to me to be clearly "unavailable for others". No lock will prevent other clients from *trying* to execute an update statement; some kinds will make them wait. What do you really want?

Comment: @Mike Sherrill'Cat Recall' The problem is, that I don't know, if user wants to update data in the moment of calling *select* statement. It's clear after any *update*. But it's too late.

Comment: You *can't* know what other users want to do. Read about [PostgreSQL transaction isolation levels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall' I've read it. I have working application on db2. Now I want this application to work the same way on postgre. But it seems impossible :(.

Comment: What transaction isolation level are you using on DB2? Edit your question, and insert a link to the DB2 documentation.

Comment: READ_COMMITTED Users can concurrently read data until one of them calls 'update'. Then affected table is locked and other users get exception until 'commit' is called.

Comment: Depending on your version of DB2, Cursor Stability (aka Read Committed) will return the _prior_ value of a cell if the row has been locked for update.  That is, it acts as if the row was read and returned  before the updating statement took place, even if that wasn't actually the case.  So even your DB2 application may not be doing what you expect.  IOW, the idea is "fix your application to work in a concurrent environment".

Comment: "READ COMMITTED" is a standard SQL isolation level. It's not a DB2 isolation level--CURSOR STABILITY is--and [CS doesn't lock a table](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/6661.cursor-stability-cs). "Compared to RR and RS, CS provides more concurrency; however, because it allows other users to access the pages or rows a given program has already read in the midst of a process, this isolation level may allow the data to be changed by another program without the knowledge of the original program."

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I don't mind if user gets older data. I want user get exception, when other user **updates** data (during open transaction).

Comment: @agad - most isolation levels don't throw exceptions during contention, they either block (wait) until the other commit is released, or ignore the locked row.  Especially if your process is "read row, think about it, then _maybe_ update it", the database has no way to know what should have happened.  At minimum, you'd need to move the `SELECT` inside the transaction, and potentially lock the entire table (bad, for several reasons).  You're probably better off doing an insert-from-select or something, but we need more info.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse This is what I've thought about: inject `select for update` before any update question :-(. Originally I thought, that it exists an easier way to get PostgreSql work as DB2. But it seems impossible :-(

Comment: @agad - What is it that your app is doing, what is it's actual flow?  Can we get some detail?  You can't really stop somebody else's read (among other things, they can just say, "ignore other people's locks").  `SELECT FOR UPDATE` would give you an exclusive write lock, but it's generally better to avoid pessimistic locking like that (even in DB2).  For one thing... is it common for your app to fight for a row?  Then you should fix your app.  You usually want transactions to be short, which usually precludes pessimistic locking.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse most of users just read data from db. But sometimes somebody modifies the data. I do not mind if a user reads unactual data, but I need to avoid two users change the data in the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I think I get what you're going for.
This isn't a "transaction" problem per se (and depending on the number of tables to deal with and the required statements, you may not even need one), it's an *application design* problem.  You have two general ways to deal with this; optimistic and pessimistic locking.

Pessimistic locking is explicitly taking and holding a lock.  It's best used when you can guarantee that you **will** be changing the row plus stuff related to it, and when your transactions will be *short*.  You would use it in situations like updating "current balance" when adding sales to an account, once a purchase has been made (update will happen, short transaction duration time because no further choices to be made at that point).  Pessimistic locking becomes frustrating if a user reads a row and then goes to lunch (or on vacation...).

Optimistic locking is reading a row (or set of), and **not** taking any sort of db-layer lock.  It's best used if you're just reading through rows, without any immediate plan to update any of them.  Usually, row data will include a "version" value (incremented counter or last updated timestamp).  If your application goes to update the row, it compares the original value(s) of the data to make sure it hasn't been changed by something else first, and alerts the user if the data changed.  Most applications interfacing with users should use optimistic locking.  It does, however, require that users notice and pay attention to updated values.

Note that, because a lock is rarely (and for a short period) taken in optimistic locking, it usually will not conflict with a separate process that takes a pessimistic lock.  A pessimistic locking app would prevent an optimistic one from updating locked rows, but not reading them.
Also note that this doesn't usually apply to bulk updates, which will have almost no user interaction (if any).

---

## tl;dr

**Don't** lock your rows on read.  Just compare the old value(s) with what the app last read, and reject the update if they don't match (and alert the user).  Train your users to respond appropriately.

Comment: Although it is not the answer I have looked for I mark this answer as correct. I just can't believe, that a thing, that works so beautifully in DB2 without any effort is not possible in PostgreSql :-(

Comment: @agad - I'm reasonably convinced that your DB2 app is 1] not actually doing what you expect (at least not completely, see my first comment on your question), and 2] not acting in the best interests of your users (lock contention being too likely).  Additionally, `SELECT FOR UPDATE` shouldn't be used to scroll through rows - your current problem is you have two processes doing that for the same row, which of course conflicts.  But doing a `SELECT` without a lock first during scroll puts you right back to this answer again....

Comment: Application has worked for a few years (and works still). Nobody has complain about it for this time. Users are happy, that they see actual data and know in case somebody is updating it. The problem raised with the request to make application working on Postgre too. Current application led to db inconsistency, when trying to run against Postgre, because 2 users updated the db in the same time.

Comment: @agad - depending on your actual application design, they might not be seeing "actual" data.  For instance, if you scroll through a cursor, `CURSOR STABILITY` will actually release the lock when fetching the next row (returning multiple rows only locks the last one, essentially).  It also doesn't prevent your application from reading a row after another process updates it, but _before_ the new data is committed (it'll see the old data).   Nasty race conditions.  It gets worse if you're serving this as a web page/over a network, because you have **no**clue when you're getting a response....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `select for update` try a "row exclusive" table lock:

```
LOCK TABLE YourTable IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html), this lock:

> The commands UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT acquire this lock mode on the
>   target table (in addition to ACCESS SHARE locks on any other
>   referenced tables). In general, this lock mode will be acquired by any
>   command that modifies data in a table.

Note that the name of the lock is confusing, but it does lock the entire table:

> Remember that all of these lock modes are table-level locks, even if
>   the name contains the word "row"; the names of the lock modes are
>   historical

Comment: According the documentation it looks fine, but when I tried it, the exception wasn't thrown in the moment of updating the table, but when commit was called